# angular service worker cached index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, service-worker, angular-service-worker

We have an angular 7 app set up with Angular Service Worker (ngsw-worker). We discovered that our `index.html` file was cached, which caused our site to not work every time we did a new release (due to the index.html file pointing to the old `css` and `js` files).
I removed the service worker from our application and re-deployed that, but it seems as though people still have the service worker installed on their browser and the old `index.html` is still being cached for them.
What can I do to get the service worker to update and not cache the `index.html`? I thought the service worker updated itself after 24 hours. How can I get the `index.html` to be removed from the service worker cache for some of our users?

Comment: you need https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwUpdate... with more details on https://alligator.io/angular/service-worker-updates/

Comment: the SwUpdate is checking new service version is available, if yes then download new version but it not refect immediately but it will reflect in next page refresh or reload.

Comment: I had the same problem. I posted my answer here how I solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68211878/14389830